# Someone removed a commit from remote repo after I pulled it, how do I keep it locally on the next git pull?

Tags: git

Someone removed a commit from the remote repository after I had done a git pull.

Locally I now have these commits:

```
$ git log --oneline
a7f2d6a commit x
29087ce commit y
8a851c8 commit z
```

But `a7f2d6a commit x` was removed from the remote repository. What do I have to do so that the next git pull doesn't remove it from my local commits? I would like to further push it back to the remote repo after I do some more work.

Comment: If that commit is on your local branch you shouldn't have to do anything at all.

Comment: If `x` is really the top line, it means you can just push it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can create a branch base on the branch that contains the commit and after that merge it to the original branch.